# How to debug an ajax request raising "Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I have a Rails app on Heroku that is crashing with `Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)`.

I've tracked this issue to pages that contain several asynchronous requests. The errors appears to coincide with ajax requests to build remote [datatables](https://datatables.net).

The problem is, I can't figure out why these errors are being raised.

I thought perhaps the databse queries and controller actions behind the ajaxified datatables might be running slowly. But if I examine these in development using miniprofiler, the requests appear very efficent.

Then I thought, perhaps the server is receiving multiple simultaneous requests, and this is overloading the heroku dyno. But I ramped the dynos up to a very high number, and still see the error.

What would be a sensible way to start identfying and debugging what is causing this memory error? I've not had to solve a issue like this before.

Comment: Do you have a significantly large database in production? In that case you may want to us pgbackups to mirror the database and run some metrics in development against it. The culprit is often 1-to-many relations where autoloading loads vast amounts of records into memory.

Comment: thanks @max. the production database is larger than development, but not huge. The largest model is < 10,000 rows. But when these errors are raised, the queries being run are all paginated. So I had thought that only the 10 paginated records should be loaded into memory. Is this correct?

Comment: Thats very difficult to answer since it depends on exactly what the query is - but yes rails will not load records which are not fetched by the query. What often happens is that if you do `Foo.joins(:bars).limit(10)` the `LIMIT` clause is applied to `foos` but not `bars`.

Comment: thanks @max (and sorry for slow reply). These queries are using `includes` rather than `joins`, does the same issue apply? And if so, what is the best way to reduce the memory overhead? I have not encountered this issue before, can you recommend any information?

Answer (score 3):

Memory is allocated per-dyno on Heroku so adding more dynos will probably not actually solve the problem if it is code-level since it will cause each dyno to exceed its memory limit individually costing you lots of money and not actually solving the problem.

You're better off scaling horozontally and using Performance-L dynos. This will increase each dyno up to 14GB of memory. You can then use metrics to see how much memory is being used. If the amount of user memory manages to use up all 14GB then you may have a memory leak in one of your dependencies.

Comment: thanks @Max Woolf. What would be the best way to identify if a memory leak exists? It is odd that this issue is only occurring on a few ajax requests, especially as all of these requests are performing paginated queries, so only 10 records should be loaded into memory. How can is identify what is eating up memory?